# Constraining child windows

Tags: wpf

I'm writing a WPF application to control an industrial process.    The main window class spawns child windows, each to control a separate piece of equipment. These child windows can be dragged but not resized.

The child windows are owned by the parent so they stay on top, but the problem this creates is that they can be dragged on top of the main window menu, which is considered aesthetically unacceptable by my client.

It would be OK if the child window goes under the menu or if it goes right up to the menu and stops but it's not OK to obscure the main menu.     How can I achieve this?   Can it be done within WPF without going into Win32 and unmanaged code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set Topmost=True on the parent window, and make it only contain the main menu. So, you'd basically have one window for the main menu and a couple of others for everything else. Or, if you can't do that, you can create a main menu window with Topmost=True as a child window of your parent, and move both of them together whenever one of them changes position.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your first proposal -  do you mean the main window would be a little thin one at the top just to hold the menu, and it would have another Window logically inside of it, but physically below it on the screen?    In WPF Window is a root element (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.aspx ) so it can't be contained by another element.    Could you describe how you would do the XAML for this or would you build it all in the code behind?  Thanks in advance.